# While executing script it will launch URL in emulator and rest of line are not executing in karate framework

Tags: karate

When i executing script it will launch URL"www.google.com" in emulator and rest of line are not executing.
**"Please suggest me the solution"** Is this way to write elements?
Environment details:
JDK 1.8
Appium v1.17
Node js v12.18
Andriod stuido v4

Feature file:
Feature: Testing Mobile

Scenario: launch chrome in appium

```
* configure driver = 
"""
{ 
    type: 'android', 
    webDriverPath : "/wd/hub", 
    start: true, 
    httpConfig : { readTimeout: 120000 }
}
"""
* def desiredConfig = 
"""
{
   "newCommandTimeout" : 300,
   "platformVersion" : "10.0",
   "platformName" : "Android",
   "connectHardwareKeyboard" : true,
   "deviceName" : "emulator-5554",
   "avd" : "Pixel_2_API_29",
   "automationName" : "UiAutomator2",
   "browserName" : "Chrome" ,
   "chromedriverExecutable" : "C:/Users/abc/Downloads/chromedriver_win32_2/chromedriver.exe"
  }
"""
    * driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(desiredConfig)"} }
    * driver 'http://google.com'
      And delay(4000)
    * driver click("//a[text()='Images']")
    # driver.input("//input[@name='q']", 'karate dsl')
```

**Logs in console:**

```
10:31:16.654 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub
/session/3b12fd81-db3b-421e-8218-b94c1ed331b5/element
10:31:16.695 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//a[text()
='Images']"}
10:31:16.698 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [MJSONWP (3b12fd81)] Calling AppiumDrive
r.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//a[text()='Images']","3b12fd81-db3b-421e-8218-b94c1ed331b5"]
10:31:16.699 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies fo
r this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
10:31:16.702 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for cond
ition
10:31:16.703 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command
 name 'findElement'
10:31:16.706 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [
POST http://127.0.0.1:8203/wd/hub/session/600582cc-a05b-422e-b886-7daeff02de45/element] with body: {"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='Images']","context":"","multiple":false}
10:31:17.466 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [WD Proxy] Got response with status 404: {"sessi
onId":"600582cc-a05b-422e-b886-7daeff02de45","value":{"error":"no such element","message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters","stacktrace":"io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.ElementNotFoundException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.findElement(FindElement.java:102)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.safeHandle(FindElement.java:72)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:38)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:252)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:242)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:51)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerCon...
10:31:17.467 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'no such el
ement' to NoSuchElementError
10:31:17.474 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 823.75
5 < 500
5 < Connection: keep-alive
5 < Content-Length: 164
5 < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
5 < Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2020 05:01:17 GMT
5 < ETag: W/"a4-/qNMwkKiq6QWZf9aZdImFcg10wM"
5 < Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override
5 < X-Powered-By: Express
{"status":7,"value":{"message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."},"sessionId":"3b12fd81-db3b-421e-8218-b94c1ed331b5"}

10:31:17.478 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [MJSONWP (3b12fd81)] Encountered interna
l error running command: NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
10:31:17.484 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [MJSONWP (3b12fd81)]     at AndroidUiaut
omator2Driver.findElOrEls (C:\Users\M1058955\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\find.js:75:11)
10:31:17.484 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] WARN  com.intuit.karate - http response code: 500, response: {"sessionId":"3b12fd81-db3b-421e-8218-b94c1ed331b5","value":{"message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."},"status":7}, request: [method: POST, responseTime: 823.7536, body: {"using":"xpath","value":"//a[text()='Images']"}]
10:31:17.484 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/3b12fd81-db
3b-421e-8218-b94c1ed331b5/element 500 819 ms - 164
10:31:17.484 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] WARN  c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - locator failed, will retry once: {"sessionId":"3b12fd81-db3b-421e-8218-b94c1ed331b5","value":{"message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."},"status":7}
10:31:17.485 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [HTTP] 
10:31:20.490 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:
6 > POST http://localhost:50636/wd/hub/session/3b12fd81-db3b-421e-8218-b94c1ed331b5/element
6 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
6 > Connection: Keep-Alive
6 > Content-Length: 48
6 > Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
6 > Host: localhost:50636
6 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/1.8.0_181)
{"using":"xpath","value":"//a[text()='Images']"}

10:31:20.531 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub
/session/3b12fd81-db3b-421e-8218-b94c1ed331b5/element
10:31:20.532 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//a[text()
='Images']"}
10:31:20.533 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [MJSONWP (3b12fd81)] Calling AppiumDrive
r.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//a[text()='Images']","3b12fd81-db3b-421e-8218-b94c1ed331b5"]
10:31:20.534 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies fo
r this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
10:31:20.535 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for cond
ition
10:31:20.536 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command
 name 'findElement'
10:31:20.536 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [
POST http://127.0.0.1:8203/wd/hub/session/600582cc-a05b-422e-b886-7daeff02de45/element] with body: {"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='Images']","context":"","multiple":false}
10:31:21.026 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [WD Proxy] Got response with status 404: {"sessi
onId":"600582cc-a05b-422e-b886-7daeff02de45","value":{"error":"no such element","message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters","stacktrace":"io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.ElementNotFoundException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.findElement(FindElement.java:102)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.safeHandle(FindElement.java:72)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:38)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:252)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:242)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:51)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerCon...
10:31:21.027 [android_1593579654225] DEBUG c.i.k.driver.android_1593579654225 - [debug] [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'no such el
ement' to NoSuchElementError
10:31:21.028 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 498.60
6 < 500
```

Answer (score 1):

can you please try karate version `0.9.6.RC3` ?, maybe based on you location `Images` locator might be changing?

**xpath**

```
Given driver 'https://www.google.com'
Then waitForUrl('https://www.google.com')
And click("//a[text()='Images']")
And input("//input[@name='q']", 'karate dsl')
```

should work with this version of karate and appium `1.17.1`.

Comment: request to `appium` is actually going as `xpath`, and the above snippet is working for me on `Android`

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded jar from https://libraries.io/maven/com.intuit.karate:karate-apache/0.9.6.RC3 - Jar Name is " karate-apache-0.9.6.RC3" and using same Appium version. But still am unable to execute these scripts and getting same logs.Please provide solution.

Comment: is your emulator launching `Chrome` and opening `google.com` ? is `Images` visible?

Comment: how are you identifying elements? you can try device tool bar option as mentioned here -> https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode and inspect your `xpath`

Comment: Yes Opening Chrome-launch "google.com" yes Visible Image.

Comment: Open chrome->Press F12->Then find the which component to be find will go and inspect then we take xpath.Copy xpath , paste in feature file. This is way am doing.In my  emulator chrome v74.0.3739 but system chrome v 83.0.4103. Is this issue script is failing??

Comment: instead of `google.com` can you try some other websites and check if still its failing for any `xpath` ? you can also follow this process https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Yes , i can able to launch "https://www.usa.philips.com/" but rest of lines are not executing. Okay. Thank You.